# file edited via github

Tags: linux, github

I have a repository in which I edited file online using github online editor. My question is that now how can I reflect those changes to the files on my local system. How can I update the same file on my system which is updated by me on github

Comment: Did `git pull` not work?

Comment: It say this "You asked me to pull without telling me which branch you
want to merge with, and 'branch.master.merge' in
your configuration file does not tell me, either. Please
specify which branch you want to use on the command line and"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must run next command in repo directory:

```
git pull
```

You may get the following error message:

> You asked me to pull without telling me which branch you want to merge with, and 'branch.master.merge' in your configuration file does not tell me, either. Please specify which branch you want to use on the command line

If so, try this:

```
git pull origin master
```

See also `man git-pull` for more information.

Comment: I tried but got this "You asked me to pull without telling me which branch you
want to merge with, and 'branch.master.merge' in
your configuration file does not tell me, either. Please
specify which branch you want to use on the command line and
"

Comment: Try this `git pull origin master`